# remove duplicates dictionary from a list based on a specific key and value

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my current list of dictionaries:

```
list1 = [{"one" : 1, "too": 2, "three": 3}, {"one" : 10, "too": 20, "three": 30} , {"one" : 1, "too": 26, "three": 35}, {"one" : 1, "too": 236, "three": 365}]
```

I want to remove all duplicates dictionary from the list based on key "one".
that means in key "one" the value is the same at another dictionary on that list, remove it.
I want the output to be:

```
list1 = [{"one" : 1, "too": 2, "three": 3}, {"one" : 10, "too": 20, "three": 30}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep a `set` of seen values for key `"one"`. You can then use a simple loop or a tricky comprehension like the following (making use of the workings of the `or` operator):

```
list1 = [{"one" : 1, "too": 2, "three": 3}, {"one" : 10, "too": 20, "three": 30} , {"one" : 1, "too": 26, "three": 35}, {"one" : 1, "too": 236, "three": 365}]

seen = set()
list1[:] = [seen.add(d["one"]) or d for d in list1 if d["one"] not in seen]
# [{'one': 1, 'too': 2, 'three': 3}, {'one': 10, 'too': 20, 'three': 30}]
```

The slice-assignment just makes sure this is a mutation on the original list, e.g. if you want to use this to modify a function argument.
You should, in any case, build the list from scratch as repeated removals from a `list` are a badly performing anti pattern.

Comment: This only works if it's not intended to remove all copies of the duplicate entry, but to keep the first seen one.

Comment: Which is intended, I would say, judging from the OPs desired output. Otherwise you would always get an empty list, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
list1 = [{"one" : 1, "too": 2, "three": 3}, {"one" : 10, "too": 20, "three": 30} , {"one" : 1, "too": 26, "three": 35}, {"one" : 1, "too": 236, "three": 365}]

l = [d for index,d in enumerate(list1) if d["one"] not in set(map(lambda x:x["one"],list1[:index]))]
```

Result:

```
[{'one': 1, 'too': 2, 'three': 3}, {'one': 10, 'too': 20, 'three': 30}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you both the unique list as well as the unique key across the list.

Code:

```
list1 = [{"one" : 1, "too": 2, "three": 3}, {"one" : 10, "too": 20, "three": 30} , {"one" : 1, "too": 26, "three": 35}, {"one" : 1, "too": 236, "three": 365}]
list2=[]
unikey=[]

for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    if list1[i]['one']:

        if list1[i]['one'] not in unikey:
            unikey.append(list1[i]['one'])
            list2.append(list1[i])

print('Unique List -> ',list2)
print('Unique Keys -> ', unikey)
```

Result:

```
Unique List ->  [{'one': 1, 'too': 2, 'three': 3}, {'one': 10, 'too': 20, 'three': 30}]
Unique Keys ->  [1, 10]
```